# IE attach event to checkbox?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an html list of checkboxes but I don't know how to get the `document.attachEvent` to find those checkboxes on an `onclick`?

I wasn't sure if I could set the event model specific to the IE then in a `document.attachEvent` create a for loop that goes through every checkbox and handles each one? Also, my checkboxes are of all different names so I can't `checkboxname.attachEvent` unless I did that to each one.

My elements are dynamics enough that I tried adding en event to the broadest ancestor, which was the document to that I could use the event to get the target and type with no avail.

Comment: you might consider using jQuery and event delegation (or delegating the events yourself).

Comment: I really can't tell what you're asking. `document.attachEvent` doesn't "find" anything. You need to find the elements. Ultimately you either need to bind handlers to each, or bind to an ancestor, and figure out what was clicked.

Comment: You can get the clicked checkbox using `window.event.srcElement`, or, if you've passed the event object to handler function in its arguments, you can use it instead of `window.event`. If this doesn't solve your problem, please show some code...

Comment: @Teemu - Here's some code: http://jsfiddle.net/Arandolph0/jxjW9/26/ What I am having problems with is that I've read that in IE the format that I have won't work. Such as the third parameter and then the error that the 'this.e' isn't working?

Comment: @Crazy Train - Why doesn't this work to ask simply http://jsfiddle.net/Arandolph0/Na2tx/

Comment: @AprilRandolph The [snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/Arandolph0/Na2tx/) in the fiddle works, just pick `No wrap - in <head>` from "Frameworks & Extensions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some fixes to your code:

```
document.attachEvent('onclick', function (e) {
    var target = e.srcElement;
    if (target.type === 'checkbox') {
        if(target.checked){
            button.disabled = false;
        } else {
            button.disabled = true;
        }       
    } 
});
```

The third argument is not used in IE's event handling model. `e.srcElement` refers to the clicked element.

I'd suggest you to wrap the checkbox(es) in a `div` or some other element, and then attach the event listener to the wrapper. When your page gets larger, checking all clicks on the document will be a time consuming operation. If you've only one checkbox, it's better to attach the handler to itself ofcourse.

Comment: I'm afraid there's not practical way. Only using a wrapper will solve the problem properly. You've a `form` element for the inputs? If so, you could attach a click eventhandler to it instead of `document`.

Comment: There is a problem with the conditional statement above that should be '==' but the code works great. Thanks.

Comment: @AprilRandolph Haha... I copy-pasted it from your fiddle :D, fixed.

Comment: @AprilRandolph You can also do something like in this [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/3McwL/4/), if you've a lot of checkboxes. (The fiddle works only in IE).